# Subsetting everything but a given index in a list (R)

Tags: r, list

Suppose I have a list of data frames.  I am iterating through the list and removing one item (aka one data frame) of the list, and then rbinding the remaining items (aka data frames) of the list to create one final dataframe.

Can you help me how to remove a given index from a list and keep the rest?

Thanks!!! Example code below

```
testDF1 = data.frame(a = c(1,2,3,4,5), b = c(10,20,30,40,50))
testDF2 = data.frame(a = c(11,12,13,14,15), b = c(110,120,130,140,150))
testDF3 = data.frame(a = c(21,22,23,24,25), b = c(210,220,230,240,250))
testDF4 = data.frame(a = c(31,32,33,34,35), b = c(310,320,330,340,350))
testDF5 = data.frame(a = c(41,42,43,44,45), b = c(410,420,430,440,450))

myList = list(DF1 = testDF1, DF2 = testDF2, DF3 = testDF3, DF4 = testDF4, DF5 = testDF5)

for (i in 1:length(myList)) {

   chosenItem = myList[[i]]
   removedItemList = myList - chosenItem   ## HELP HERE!!!!
   updatedList = do.call("rbind", removedItemList)

}
```

Comment: Can you please provide the expected output?

Comment: What do you mean by *"one item of the list"*? One dataframe of the list?

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out...

```
for (i in 1:length(myList)) {

   chosenItem = myList[[i]]
   removedItemList = myList[i]
   updatedList = do.call("rbind", removedItemList)

}
```

Comment: Are you aware that that's just `myList[[5]]` or `myList$DF5`? Run `row.names(updatedList) <- NULL; identical(updatedList, myList[[5]])` and see what I mean.